# Randomly failing Clone() in Snap.SVG

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

I'm having a problem where occasionally `clone()` is failing inside `Element.insertAfter` because `el.node.parentNode` is null.

Inside top level html

```
Snap.load(path, function (data) {
    window.picto_svg = data.select('svg');
    ...
    jQuery('#content').load('interior.html');
});
```

Inside interior.html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var svg_copy = picto_svg.clone();
});
```

Am I just getting lucky that it usually doesn't fail? I don't want to display the svg before cloning. I end up cloning it and adjusting the clone several times, so just want to keep one pure one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seems I was getting lucky. To reliably clone an Element, it must have been appended first. I appended to a hidden div and the random failures went away.

```
Snap.load(path, function (data) {
  var placeholder = Snap('#placeholder');
  var appended = placeholder.append(data);
  window.picto_svg = placeholder.select('svg');
```

http://codepen.io/matelich/pen/BKyVYv

Answer (score 0):

I would probably post more code on a jsfiddle, as there's not enough information to be sure.

However, my first guess would that you need to move this line..

```
var svg_copy = picto_svg.clone();
```

Inside the Snap.load function. The problem is possibly that you are trying to create a clone before the file has been loaded, so sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Its also not clear if you are appending the svg or not as well, but first I would make sure that all function calls and variable assignments that rely on a file being loaded are called from the load function.

Comment: picto_svg is never appended to anything, only its clones. I didn't work on a fiddle because I suspected the jQuery.load was a factor. I'll work one up, I guess

Comment: Make sure you do the clone() from the Snap.load() callback (or in a function called from that).

Comment: It is, the jQuery.load() is within Snap.load()'s callback.

Comment: Argh. My data.select('svg') call is not working in my pen - http://codepen.io/matelich/pen/BKyVYv

Comment: Tbh I'm a bit surprised things like clone() etc work at all on a fragment.

Comment: Ok, got my pen working. Maybe the fix I needed there will help my real use case.

Comment: You can always just append it with visibility 0 or whatever.